# How to highlight all occurrences of a keyword in .pptx file using python

Tags: python, full-text-search, powerpoint, python-pptx

I am able to access the run level of the of the paragraph and also the cell of the table where the keyword is occurring but i don't know how to highlight it. I've read that Powerpoint stores data with uncertainty within runs so i can clear the runs and highlight the text but don't know how to do so here's my code.

```
from pptx import Presentation 
import os

from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor

directory = "D:\Python_Scripts\Email Analysis"

keyword = "payable"

AttachmentsList = os.listdir(directory)

pptxList = list()
foundDocList = list()

for file in AttachmentsList:
    if file.endswith(".pptx"):
        pptxList.append(os.path.join(directory, file))

for ppt in pptxList:
    prs = Presentation(ppt)
    for slide in prs.slides:
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if shape.has_text_frame:
                for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
                    for run in paragraph.runs:
                        if keyword.lower() in run.text.lower():
                            # code to clear runs and highlight keywords
                            prs.save("output.pptx")
            if shape.has_table:
                for row in shape.table.rows:
                    for cell in row.cells:
                        if keyword.lower() in cell.text.lower():
                             # code to clear runs and highlight keywords
                             prs.save("output.pptx")
```

Comment: `python-pptx` has no API support for highlighting in the current release (0.6.19). Also, if it did it would be applied to a run object and that would mean you'd need to isolate the run(s) that you want to highlight. There's currently no API support for that either.

Comment: Since runs contains formatting of text. It'll be fine if i clear runs highlighting part is very important to me if highlight is not possible i can change the color of font of keyword. A similar [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298385/highlighting-words-in-an-docx-file-using-python-docx-gives-incorrect-results) of this in .docx format. Any help on this could be good

Answer (score 1):

Does the following help?

```
def set_highlight(run, color):
    # get run properties
    rPr = run._r.get_or_add_rPr()

    # Create highlight element
    hl = OxmlElement("a:highlight")

    # Create specify RGB Colour element with color specified
    srgbClr = OxmlElement("a:srgbClr")
    setattr(srgbClr, "val", color)

    # Add colour specification to highlight element
    hl.append(srgbClr)

    # Add highlight element to run properties
    rPr.append(hl)

    return run
```

It's from my [md2pptx](https://github.com/MartinPacker/md2pptx) open source project.

Comment: Does `color` require hex values of color ?

Comment: I think so. I haven't seen colour names.