# Highlighting words in existing .docx using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

I want to write a python script that searches a word in a .docx file and highlights or changes the font color over the word. (I'm new to the language and this is the project I chose to learn it, so sorry if the answers to any of my questions should be obvious)

I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46116389/highlight-text-using-python-docx) and copied the code as a base

```
import docx
from docx.enum.text import WD_COLOR_INDEX

dstPath = './my/file/path'
keyword = 'someWord'
document = docx.Document(dstPath)

def wordSearch(document, keyword, dstPath):
    for p in document.paragraphs:
        if keyword in p.text:
            for run in p.runs:
                if keyword in run.text:
                    temp = run.text.split(keyword)
                    run.clear()
                    for i in range(len(temp) - 1):
                        run.add_text(temp[i])
                        run.add_text(keyword)
                        run.font.highlight_color = WD_COLOR_INDEX.YELLOW
    document.save(dstPath)
```

It doesn't exactly do what I want (it highlights the whole run not just the word) and I think I could be able to fix that by maybe making each of the string ins `temp` their own run and then adding the keyword in between them or something along those lines.
But I hoped there would be a better solution then to split the string at the keyword since this could cause problems when the string starts or ends with the word and I don't know if there is an elegant way of fixing this problem.

Also I think currently my search is case sensitive, is there a simple way I can change that?

Comment: Regarding your case sensitivity. You can modify the your `if` conditions to something like `if keyword.lower() in text.lower()`.

Comment: Check out this existing answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298385/highlighting-words-in-an-docx-file-using-python-docx-gives-incorrect-results/55306305#55306305 and see if that doesn't move you forward. If you have a more specific question after that you can ask it as a new question. As you'll see, this is a challenging task; if learning is your primary interest you might want to pick a different first project :)