# How to create a syntax highlighted .docx with python?

Tags: python, lxml, docx, highlight, python-docx

iam new to python and currently trying to write a program that reads multiple .xml files from the file explorer and displays them in .docx file. (Formatted and colour highlighted)

I tried using python-docx and lxml to first read the xml as a formatted string and afterwards write it into the .docx file.

Unfortunately i cant figure out a way to colour highlight the text in the .docx file like for example when using notepad++.

Maybe you guys have some ideas?

My approach:

```
from docx import Document
from lxml import etree

store_location = "xyz.docx"
template_path = "abc.docx"

doc = Document(template_path)

xml_et = etree.parse("example.xml")
xml_string = etree.tostring(xml_et,pretty_print=True,encoding=str)
doc.add_paragraph(xml_string)
        
doc.save(store_location)
```

Comment: this should help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46116389/highlight-text-using-python-docx

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to put colour on each word or character which have a special meaning in XML. That's huge work. So firstly you'll need a syntax highlighter. In python, the game breaker one is [Pygments](https://pygments.org/docs/quickstart/). You'll use the XML `Lexer`.

Once you have your code highlighted, you have to insert it in your document. You have then 2 solutions :

- Select the `Formatter` you prefer and iterate over token then add it to your document through `python-docx` interface.
- Directly add xml representation supported by OpenDocument. But it seems there's no `Formatter` for OpenDocument, so you'll have to create a bridge with one existing `Formatter` or even better develop the new output for `Pygments`.

I think the best solution is the second one. Firstly, you should take a quick look at [ISO/IEC 26300 OpenDocument](https://www.open-std.org/keld/iso26300-odf/is26300/OpenDocument-v1.0ed2-cs1.html#15.4.3.Color%7Coutline), then open a question or an issue on the [Pygments' git](https://github.com/pygments/pygments).